# amazon s3 download "Access denied" c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to download the files from amazon s3 using c# code.

The code is working fine in server. But in my personal laptop when i run the same code, i am getting an error saying "Access Denied".

```
private IAmazonS3 awsclient;
awsbucket = "MyBucketName";
            awsaccesskey = "MyaccessKey";
            awssecretkey = "MySecretKey";
            awsregion = RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
            awscredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsaccesskey, awssecretkey);
            awsclient = Connect(awscredentials, awsregion);

 var request = new GetObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = awsbucket,
                    Key = "foldername/" + fileName
                };
GetObjectResponse response = awsclient.GetObject(request)
```

The above line is throwing error "Access denied"

But this code when i compile and run from my server it is working fine.

So what is missing in my laptop? What i need to install or configure so that this code will run from my Laptop also?

Comment: I installed Cloudberry for Amazon s3 in my laptop and tried to do the same. Connection is successful, even external bucket i am able to add. But when i tried to double click the bucket. I got the same Access Denied error 403 error. So how to set this access?

Comment: check you policies where restricted ip might access to bucket. also check permissions settings

Comment: I came to know only white-listed will work. I am not sure how to set my laptop as white listed